What is the default serif, sans-serif and monospace font-family for Windows 11?
In approximately build 22631.3737 (and onward) what are the default fonts rendered for the following font-families?

font-family: serif;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-family: monospace;

I ask partially because on most browsers, they appear to correlate with system fonts, yet on many embedded browsers, they appear to render as the Segoe UI fallback (like VS Code does) whereas on every Linux-based OS I've used, these aliases work perfectly.
